# Regex for finding a specific pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex to test if a string contains `]][[`. For ex:`[[t]][[t]]`.

I am able to find a string which ends with `]]` using the pattern:

```
RegExp(/]]/)
```

But if i try to use the pattern:

```
RegExp(/]\]\(?=\[\[)/)
```

for testing `[[t]][[t]]`, the console displays the following error:

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid regular expression: /]\]\(?=\[\[)/: Unmatched ')'
```

Comment: Why use regex? `yourString.indexOf(']][[') !== -1` works perfectly.

Comment: @user3875740 Please take a look at my answer; I believe it addresses all of your issues. If so, please remember to accept it! :)

Comment: how to find if there exist empty brackets and  if bracket arent even in a string raise alert for eg:[[]],[[lc_1] or [lc_1]] in [[lc_1]]+2+[[]]+[[]+[lc_]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you have a syntax error:

You are escaping `(` with `\(`, so you get the `Unmatched ')'` error in `\(?=\[\[)`.

### How to fix it:

The best way to do this depends on exactly what you want.

If you just want to check that the string contains `]][[`, don't use a regex:

```
if (yourString.indexOf(']][[') !== -1) {
    // do something
}
```

If you really want to use a regex, you need to escape `[`s but not `]`s:

```
if (/]]\[\[/.test(yourString)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you really want to use a regex and not capture the `[[`:

```
if (/]](?=\[\[)/.test(yourString)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to check for matching `[[` and `]]` (like `[[t]]`):

```
if (/\[\[[^[\]]*]]/.test(yourString)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to check for two `[[..]]` strings back-to-back:

```
if (/(\[\[[^[\]]*]]){2}/.test(yourString)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to check for one `[[..]]` string, followed by *exactly the same string* (`[[t]][[t]]` but not `[[foo]][[bar]]`):

```
if (/(\[\[[^[\]]*]])\1/.test(yourString)) {
    // do something
}
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/dwm46/4/) of all of the above, along with a bunch of unit tests to demonstrate how each of these works.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (/]]\[\[/.test(yourString)) {
    // It matches!
} else {
    // Nah, no match...
}
```

Note that we need to escape the two opening braces with `\[`, but the closing braces `]` do not need escaping as there is no potential confusion with a character class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the opening square brackets because it has a special meaning in regex which represents the start of a character class.

```
]](?=\[\[)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one, this regex must match everything you need:

```
(\w*[\[\]]+\w*)+
```

But if for every open bracket `[` there must be a closed bracket `]`, that's different.
What exactly you want?

Comment: This is completely wrong. It matches `foo`, which obviously doesn't contain `]][[`.

Comment: This is still completely wrong. Now it matches strings like `[]` or `[]]]]`. OP wrote, "I want to write a regex to test if a string contains `]][[`." That does not necessarily mean matching `[` and `]` brackets, and it  certainly isn't satisfied by this regex.

Comment: Also, FYI, `(\w|\d)` is redundant -- `\w` will match digits. I would suggest you test your regex at http://regex101.com/ or https://www.debuggex.com/, which will explain how the regex works and help you understand them better.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Take a look at [this demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yM_SLKieGNfHmSyO). You're still trying to match things like `[]` or `[[t]]`, and even that isn't working because you are matching things like `[]]]` or `[foo[bar[baz[[[[[[[[[]`. OP explicitly wants strings containing `]][[`. Your regex doesn't even match `]][[`. Look at what the other answers are doing; you are misreading the question.

Comment: I tried every string that was in my mind, and it match all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. Did you read the question? It doesn't do what OP asked for. It's not good enough if it matches `[[t]]`; that's wrong. It should match only if `]][[` is present.